# AWS- I have a CFT that integrates a Lambda Function with API Gateway. What resources do I use to connect my API Gateway to a Custom DNS name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I want something like

"example.com/helloworld" to display the Hello World message I have stored in my Lambda Function. My CFN creates a Lambda Function, and creates an API, then connects both of these services.

However, I don't know what resources to use to connect my API Gateway to a Custom DNS name like "example.com/helloworld" so I can display "Hello World" from my Lambda Function in a browser. What resources do I need here?

Answer (score 0):

First step is to go to the "Custom domain names" section of your API Gateway and configure a domain for a particular API and stage. This will instruct the CloudFront distribution that serves your API (API Gateway is always served by a CloudFront in the background) to accept network requests for that domain and forward them to a particular stage (e.g. testing or production). This way you can have different domains instead of URL paths for different stages and use just the endpoint (part after the stage) of the URL.

Then you need to own a domain name (e.g. `example.com`) and point your domain's CNAME record to the domain that you get when you configure your API Gateway's custom domain.

If your domain is hosted on the AWS Route53 service, you can create just an ALIAS for the domain given to you by the API Gateway instead of the CNAME.

Comment: My domain is hosted in Route53. I created a Hosted Zone for "example-api.com". I tried to create a Record Set, chose "Yes" to Alias, then tried to place the URL from my API Gateway in the "Alias Target" field. However, what type would this be? It's not CNAME right?

Comment: @R.SMohanAravind you do not place the whole URL into the alias target, just the domain. URL = domain [+ path] [+ query string parameters] (whatever follows the domain) and DNS only routes domain, i.e. tells client which server to contact. client then tells the server which HTTP path it wants to query. use route53 to configure your domain and let the API Gateway to handle the rest of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for Cloud formation resource for connect APIGW to custom domain name ( or creating a custom domain name in APIGW ) - it is AWS::APIGateway::DomainName

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-domainname.html